# Unknown field errors when posting in Solr

Tags: json, solr, highlight

I'm new to Solr. I'm running ver. 8.3.1 on Ubuntu 18.04. So far I've successfully crawled a website via a custom script, posted the crawled content to a schemaless core and run queries against the index. Now I'd like to do highlighting.

I found highlighting-related questions [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323157/how-to-highlight-a-query-term-in-a-field-containing-html-in-solr) and [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527374/solr-strip-html-when-highlighting-with-stored-html-fields?rq=1), which recommend storing the data to be indexed in files containing two fields, one field for the original, formatted HTML and the other for the same content as unformatted text, stripped of its HTML tags.

I turned off schemaless mode and managed-schema, and have created a minimal schema.xml based on the default managed-schema. My schema contains only 3 of the predefined fields (id, *version* and *text*) and two additional fields, content_html and content_text.  Per the second answer to question 2 above, I also defined a text_html fieldtype for content_html. But the core failed to restart with that fieldtype, so I removed it. I have left all filetypes, dynamic and copy fields, etc. intact.

Here are the fields defined in schema.xml:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
<field name="_text_" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="content_html" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="content_text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

My crawler is a simple PHP script.  I've tried storing the crawled content as XML and JSON in separate attempts. With XML, PHP converted special characters to their HTML equivalents (e.g., < becomes &lt;), so I abandoned this format. JSON seems to be working, as evidenced by the fact that my script doesn't die, and spot checks of the output appear to be formatted correctly. Here's a simplified example of the script's output:

```
{
  "content_html": "<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"> ... <ul> ... <\/ul> ... etc.",
  "content_text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ... etc."
}
```

I have followed the instructions for clearing out the index prior to re-posting the documents, which are to delete by query and commit as follows:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"delete":{"query":"*:*" }}' http://localhost:8983/solr/corename/update

curl http://localhost:8983/solr/corename/update --data '<commit/>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'
```

The instructions say the data dir should be empty when this finishes, but it isn't.  The folder structure remains intact, and two files remain in the index folder, segments_a (117 bytes) and write.lock (0 bytes). There are also a number of files of various sizes in the tlog folder.

I’m sending the data to Solr with the following command:

```
sudo -u solr /opt/solr/bin/post -c corename /var/solr/data/userfiles/corename/*
```

When I post, Solr throws errors for each document and the index isn't updated. Here are the two errors I'm getting:

```
..."status":500, ... "msg":"org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Zip bomb detected!"

..."status":400, ... unknown field 'x_parsed_by'
```

The Tika error probably results from my putting large amounts of data in a single JSON field. Research tells me that this error is related to Tika's maxStringLength setting for its WriteOutContentHandler. I will ask about Tika in a separate question.

Regarding the unknown field error, my assumption is that Solr will index only the data contained in the fields I've defined in schema.xml, ignoring other fields it encounters. So, I don't know why a new field, x_parsed_by is coming into the picture and causing trouble. Perhaps my assumption is incorrect. Must I account in advance for each field that will be encountered? Seems to me this would be impossible with a large set of data unless schemaless mode is used. Perhaps, instead of using a minimal schema.xml, I should rename my core's managed-schema, which was modified by indexing, to schema.xml so that all of the fields it defines are retained. I've learned, though, that it's wise to reduce the index size if possible by eliminating unneccessary fields. How should I approach this? Perhaps there's a recommended solution for highlighting HTML content that I've missed.

What additional information can I provide to facilitate an answer?

---

After receiving MatsLindh's advice and reading the reference guide more carefully, I made the following changes which allowed me to index the data and highlight query results.

schema.xml:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
<field name="_text_" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="content_title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="content_description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="content_html" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="content_text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

JSON output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "content_title": "Title Text Here",
        "content_description": "Description text here",
        "content_html": "<!DOCTYPE html> etc.",
        "content_text": "Text from content_html, stripped of tags."
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "content_title": "Title Text Here",
        "content_description": "Description text here",
        "content_html": "<!DOCTYPE html> etc.",
        "content_text": "Text from content_html, stripped of tags."
    }
]
```

Command to index the data via /update:

```
curl 'localhost:8983/solr/corename/update?commit=true' --data-binary @/var/solr/data/userfiles/corename/content.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

Comment: What content are you actually submitting to Solr and to what endpoint? What is the indexing request? If you were just sending that JSON file to be indexed directly as content in Solr (i.e. to `/update`), I don't think Tika shouldn't be invoked at all.

Comment: @MatsLindh, I’m using the post command.  I added details to my question.  I’ll look into using /update.

Comment: If you've already structured your content, using the `/update` endpoint would be the way to go. The `post` command submits arbitrary documents to the Tika endpoint - there is no need for Tika when you already have your data structured, just create regular Solr index updates with predefined fields instead.

Comment: I was able to index the JSON data using /update.